# How can I make this paginate's paging number keep its active state after the href _dopostback is clicked in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dopostback

My current situation here is that when I press one of the link buttons, I can accurately jump out of the information on the page I want, but the pagination below has not changed, so we have no way to know which page we are on now.

code in aspx file

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptPaging" runat="server" OnItemCommand="rptPaging_ItemCommand" >  
                                            <ItemTemplate>  
                                                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkPage"  CssClass="btnPage" OnClientClick="JavaScript: return false;" 
                                                   
                                                     CommandName="Page" CommandArgument="<%# Container.DataItem %>" runat="server" Font-Bold="True"><%# Container.DataItem %>  
                                                </asp:LinkButton>  
                                            </ItemTemplate>  
                                        </asp:Repeater>
```

Code behind. this contains the current page number.

```
   public int PageNumber
    {
        get
        {
            if (ViewState["PageNumber"] != null)
            {
                return Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["PageNumber"]);
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
        set { ViewState["PageNumber"] = value; }
    }
    private int iPageSize = 50;
```

I found a way to prevent the buttons from being postback refresh css together on the Internet that is using OnClientClick to return false. Although I succeeded in making the button maintain the color after it was pressed, BUT my page was also maintained on the first page, and no matter how I pressed the paging button, it Will not jump out the data.Well, and also no any postback happen to refresh. (PS: My page is always refreshed on the same page and will not open a new page)  and the paginate is using **PagedDataSource**.

example href for paging num1 & 2 at html

```
href ="javascript:__doPostBack('rptPaging$ctl00$lnkPage','')"
href="javascript:__doPostBack('rptPaging$ctl01$lnkPage','')"
```

I need to maintain the back color of the link button the user clicked so the user can know which paging number they are stay on.